# If URL contains X and URL does not contain Y

Tags: php

If URL contains "Little_Rock_AR"

is also being registered, when

If URL contains "North_Little_Rock_AR"

How can I write the Little Rock code to say...

If URL contains "Little_Rock_AR" BUT does not contain "North"

Here is the actual code I'm using for Little Rock:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (false !== strpos($url,'little_rock_ar')) 
{
...
}

?>
```

Comment: Does it follow a `/` in the url?  You can look for `/Little_Rock_AR`.

Comment: This solution isn't good enough for me to put as an answer, but if you just need a quick one, test for "north little rock" first, and stop. Only test for "little rock" after the first test fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regullar expressions.
For you example, something like this

`~^Little_Rock_AR~` for uri begin with Little_Rock_AR

This url will help more - http://regexpal.com

Answer (score 0):

```
if (
    (false !== strpos($url,'little_rock_ar') && false === strpos($url,'north')) 
    || false !== strpos($url,'north_little_rock_ar')
) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need use regular expression and [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Something like this should work

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(preg_match('/North_Little_Rock_AR/i', $url)){
  //whatever you want
}else if(preg_match('/Little_Rock_AR/i', $url)){
  //whatever you want
}else{
//no match either
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! ... Only thing I had to change is to search for "North Little Rock" first, as "Little Rock" is inside "North Little Rock" ... So I just switched them. Have a great day Emilio! Thanks again!